# Citation: Author-comma-year in LyX (classicthesis)

Tags: lyx, natbib

I am writing my thesis in LyX using `classicthesis` and have some troubles with citation style.

Basically, I want to avoid ERT when citing and instead use LyX' built-in "Insert citation" to get Author-comma-year instead of Author-year (see image for details. Left: Output, Right: LyX input).

[image: Citation.]

### I use the following Document Settings:

Document class: Classicthesis

Class option:

```
 fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,oneside,openany,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,BCOR=5mm,footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty
```

Citation Style: Natbib; Author-year ('Numerical' is the only other option)

Bibliography style: `abbrvnat`

### In preamble:

% Citep

```
\usepackage[authoryear,round,colon]{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{autheryear}{,}{;}
```

*I am aware that similar questions have been raised, however, those threads have not solved my problem.*

Comment: is that "auth**e**ryear" in the second line of the preamble on purpose or a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `abbrvnat`. Choose `apalike`, `authordate1`, ..., `authordate4` or `chicago` instead.